# C# FlowLayoutPanel Control autosize to fit Panel

Tags: c#, .net, custom-controls, flowlayoutpanel

I have already seen previous questions concerning this topic and havent found answer. 
I have a full screen application and most of the screen is FlowLayoutPanel. On it I have added 48 forms that have image, and few textboxex. They are filled left to right and that is OK but when they can't fit on the screen, layoutpanel turns on autoscroll. I dont want that so I used autosize = true and autosizemode = growandshring for forms and also added minimum size for them so they dont disapear. That kind of works but then they have big margins between rows. What is appropriate solution to autosize forms (as controls) inside flowlayoutpanel so they all fit, and they're not too small

Comment: Is this Windows Forms or WPF?

Comment: I forgot to mention, WIndows Form

Comment: Are you sure that these margins between the rows are not actualy part of your controls? Try setting the background of your controls to a distinct color and tell if there is realy a margin between your controls or if the extra space ist part of your controls.

Comment: Yes, my controls are forms and i filled their background and still there is great amount of space